# Is it good practice to use angular-Flex layout + Bootstrap forms in angular 4 instead of using bootstrap 4 flex?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-flex-layout

Want to know if it is a good practice to use angular-Flex layout + Boostrap forms in angular 4 instead of using bootstrap 4 flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine these two libraries with no problem.

If you want to keep your bundle file size small, you can import only the parts of the Bootstrap library you use - assuming you use `scss`.

For example, to only import the forms, in your `style.scss`:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid";
```

If you're using plain css, with a little effort you would need to build this file yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion